# How can I show a coverage report generated in TeamCity in GitLlab repository page?

Tags: gitlab, teamcity

I have a Python project hosted on GitLab. I also use TeamCity for CI/CD.

I have written some tests for my project and I want to show the coverage report in the repository's page in GitLab. Currently the TeamCity build generates the report but I haven't found a way to publish it to GitLab and show it there.

From what I was able to find online my best bet is to publish the coverage report as a build artifact in TeamCity, but I haven't found a way to pull it into GitLab and show it.